# Why does there not exist a 3 regular graph of order 5?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Because the lines of a graph don't necessarily have to be straight, I don't understand how no such graphs exist. Can anyone shed some light on why this is?

Answer (score 2):

The degree $\mathrm{deg}(v)$ of a vertex $v$ is the number of its incident edges. By the [handshaking lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma), $$\sum_{v\in V} \mathrm{deg}(v) = 2\left|E\right|,$$ i.e., the sum of degrees over all vertices is twice the number of edges. This number must be even since $\left|E\right|$ is integer. In a 3-regular graph, we have $$\sum_{v\in V}\mathrm{deg}(v) = \sum_{v \in V} 3 = 3\left|V\right|.$$ However, $3\left|V\right|$ is even only if $\left|V\right|$ is even. Therefore, 3-regular graphs must have an even number of vertices.

Comment: I'm sorry, I miss typed a 8 instead of a 5!